# Adult hot milk stirrers

Tags: chocolate, milk, alcohol

I want to make some Hot milk stirrers but adding alcohol to it.
What is the recommended liquor, and how would you do the measurements :D
TIA

Answer (score 4):

There’s no “the” recommended alcohol, and flavor pairing is off topic here.

What I would do when looking for ideas for good chocolate-and-alcohol combinations is checking out truffle recipes and creamy cocktails. You will find a wide choice and also notice that

- there are more popular combinations (rum, brandy, whisky, creamy liqueurs, amaretto, orange liqueur…) and
- liquors that you will find less frequently - typically very herbal-bitter
  ones (think Jägermeister), “flavorless” ones like vodka or those that usually call for lime/lemon/tonic (like gin and tequila)

Not saying that it’s *impossible* (I came across gin truffles only last week), but for a first attempt or a gift, I’d hesitate to experiment with the latter group.

For dosage, it depends on the mug size, amount of chocolate, chosen alcohol, and, for practical reasons, capacity of your chocolate mold.

And if you’re unsure, make a hot chocolate milk without the liquor, add liquor to taste, one teaspoon at a time and you’ll have your measurement.

——-

Afterthought:
Just to avoid any confusion, I am assuming that you plan to make chocolate shells that you fill with your alcohol of choice, not trying to mix chocolate and liquor and expect that to solidify when cooled (it probably won’t). And if you’re using wooden spoons or sticks, they need to be dipped in chocolate or they will soak up the liquid and cause leakage.

Comment: Your afterthought fits with the assumption I based my answer on at the same time. I can't see any other way to do it, though it might be worth mixing cocoa into the filling, especially with very sweet liqueurs.

Comment: @ChrisH I think instinctively we both were imagining the same thing - chocolate shell, liquid filling.

Answer (score 3):

I like a dash of tasty liqueur in a hot chocolate. I don't measure it but I'd say about 20-25ml to a 250-300ml mug. I might add Drambuie, Grand Marnier, Cointreau or home made crème de cassis.

With Baileys or Tia Maria people often use a bit more, brandy I think a bit less.

Getting this sort of quantity into your stirrer isn't going to be easy. Your best bet might be to look at making liqueur chocolates, but on a stick, and with a thicker shell. Starting from a truffle recipe is likely to add too much fat (though cream is an acceptable addition to hot chocolate of course), and anyway, the proportion of liqueur or spirit in truffles is too low.

When I cook with flavoured alcohol I often reinforce the main flavours. That might be a good idea here, then you can use less for the same effect to make it easier. So for orange liqueur I might add orange oil to the chocolate, or soak orange rind in the alcohol first. In this case you can also make a garnish that matches the flavour, like a curl of candied orange peel.

Comment: Ah, for clarification, I am not suggesting _making_ truffles, just getting inspiration for flavor combinations.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the recommended liquor

That really depends on the flavor you want. Based on my own experience with this type of thing though, I would tend more towards lower-proof alcohols. The strongest stuff I’ve ever tried in hot chocolate was a dash (maybe 10ml in a 300ml mug) of green Chartreuse (55% ABV), it wasn’t bad but the alcohol was a bit strong. I’ve also done goldschläger (43.5% ABV) before in a similar amount and that was *very* good, but I’m very fond of goldschläger. In general though, I wouldn’t go for more than about 45% ABV, and would tend more towards the 10-30% range.

As far as specific flavors, look for stuff that pairs well with chocolate. Orange, mint, coconut, almond and cinnamon flavors should all work pretty well regardless of your audience. Anise and mastic should also work well, but are more of an acquired taste (a lot of people are not big on either flavor). Cherry would theoretically work, but there aren’t many cherry liqueurs other than Maraschino, and that’s way too sweet unless you’re using dark chocolate for the beverage instead of milk chocolate.

> how would you do the measurements

The goal is generally to flavor the drink, not to make it alcoholic, so you want just enough that the flavor comes through. For a 20% ABV alcohol and an assumption of a 300ml mug, I would start with about 25-30ml of alcohol (this works out to roughly 2% ABV in the final drink) unless the flavor is very delicate. Start with one or two like that, test it, and adjust from there based on the results of the testing.

Comment: I've been using up a bottle of cheap weak kirsch (French "Spiriteuex de Kirsch" 18% ) in hot chocolate. That works well